# Luby-Rackoff theorem confusion

Tags: pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation, feistel-network, luby-rackoff

The Luby-Rackoff theorem states that if a round function is a secure pseudorandom function (PRF)
then 3 rounds are sufficient to make the block cipher a pseudorandom permutation (PRP).

PRPs are invertible whereas PRFs are not. How come 3 rounds of a PRF
will make an invertible block cipher out of a non-invertible function?

Comment: (This is actually a question about the Feistel construction, not the Luby-Rackoff result.) It's not three successive invocations of the PRF, it's three rounds of the *Feistel construction*, instantiated with the PRF as the round functions. It's not hard to see that any number of Feistel rounds are invertible using the round functions in only the *forward* direction -- they do not need to be invertible. See Wikipedia for more info on the Feistel construction.

Comment: Maybe it helps to remind yourself of the fact that [Michael Luby and Charles Rackoff analyzed the **Feistel cipher construction**](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0217022). Simpler said: The answer can not be found by stricktly looking at PRFs… instead you should be looking closer at [Feistel constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher), as they show how 3 rounds of a PRF will make an invertible block cipher out of a non-invertible function.

Comment: @yyyy0000 You might want to check your browser and DNS settings, because that first link — which I have posted in my 2014 comment — is still alive and well. QED: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXIDN.jpg (Note that it's a website, not a PDF download) Hope that helps…

Comment: @yyyy0000 As an aside, here's a constructive hint: your favorite search engine is your friend. Just search for the title and authors, and you'll quickly find stuff like https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221354810_How_to_Construct_Pseudo-Random_Permutations_from_Pseudo-Random_Functions_Abstract which also offers the PDF download. Users are not search engines, but this one time, I did a quick lookup for your convenience.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.ei.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/media/ei/lehrmaterialien/sadeghi_aspekte-der-modernen-kryptogragrafie-ii/LR-Proof.pdf

Answer (score 11):

The proof is loosely as below.

Lets assume a one round Feistel network, where $2n$ bits are divided into $n$ bits each $L_0, R_0$

The encryption is defined as

$L_{1} = R_{0}, \\ R_{1} = L_0 \oplus f(R_0) $

where f is any random function (PRF) and $\oplus$ is XOR operation

Now the cipher text is $L_{2} = R_{1}, R_{2} = L_1 $

Decryption is same as encryption circuit as defined above.

The input to decryption is $L_2, R_2$.

So decryption is defined as below

$ L_{3} = R_{2} \\ R_{3} = L_{2} \oplus f(R_2) $

Where the plain text should be considered $R_3, L_3$

Now lets substitute from 
$ L_{3} = L_{1}, \\ R_{3} = R_{1} \oplus f(L_1) $

Now lets substitute further to get the plain text is $R_3, L_3$ which is $L_0, R_0$ as shown below
$ L_{3} = R_{0}, \\
 R_{3} = L_0 \oplus f(R_0) \oplus f(R_{0}) ,\\
 R_{3} = L_0 $

So it does not really matter if $f(R_0)$ is reversible or not. And the same holds good for any number of rounds.

There is also an intuitive explanation [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/1d390a/intuitive_explanation_of_a_round_function_in_a/)

Comment: Umm... this is how the overall security of a (2 branch, balanced) Feistel scheme works, may be, you can cover a little on how the proof of L-R theorem works.